# postgres ERROR: insert or update on table "xxxxx" violates foreign key contrain "xxxxx"

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

Hello
I have a main table BASECOMPANYDATA with BaseCompanyDataID as a PK. This is inhereted by
2 other tables CUSTOMERS & PRODUCTCOMPANIES. Now I have the table CONTACTS which I 
want to connect with the 2 others as the customers and the productcompanies will have 0 or 
more contacts. So I made a FK(BaseCompanyID) in CONTACTS and connected to the 
BASECOMPANYDATA PK(BaseCompanyDataID). But when I am trying to insert a contact for 
a record which exists in CUSTOMERS I get the following error:
 ERROR: insert or update on table "xxxxx" violates foreign key contrain "xxxxx"
DETAIL: Key (BaseCompanyDataID)=(17) is not present in table "BaseCompanyData".
This ID exists in the above inherited table (BaseCompanyData).
Can someone explain why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

**PS**:Well, I have 4 tables:

1.BASECOMPANYDATA with BaseCompanyDataID as PK and some other fields.
2.CUSTOMERS which inherits from the above table so it has CustomerID as PK and has the fields of the BASECOMPANYDATA table namely BaseCompanyDataID etc.
3.PRODUCTCOMPANIES which inherits from BASECOMPANYDATA so it has the fields ProductCompanyID as PK and the fields of the inherited table like BaseCompanyDataID etc.
4.CONTACTS with ContactID as PK and BaseCompanyDataID as a FK. I tried to connect the table CONTACTS with 2 different ways. a. CONTACTS->BaseCompanyID with CUSTOMERS->BaseCompanyDataID and CONTACTS->BaseCompanyID with PRODUCTCOMPANIES->BaseCompanyDataID b. CONTACTS->BaseCompanyID with BASECOMPANYDATA->BaseCompanyDataID The result was the same error. Any answer on how I can create the FK using the inheritance, if there is. Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be great if you added some line breaks to your question and maybe a snippet from your table definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read through the inheritance docs? Especially the `5.8.1. Caveats` section?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-inherit.html

...

> Similarly, if we were to specify that cities.name REFERENCES some other table, this constraint would not automatically propagate to capitals. In this case you could work around it by manually adding the same REFERENCES constraint to capitals.

edit:

**Inheritance** is only **half implemented** in Postgsresql. If you want to save typing check out **`like`** in create table

In your first question I see the person recommended exactly the same thing I said. And now you have a problem? Hmm ...

This is pseudo sql I get from your repost:

```
base
    baseid

customers(base)
    baseid
    id

products(base)
    baseid
    id

contacts
    id
    baseid references base(baseid)
```

Just do it the good old fashioned way!

```
base
    id

customers
    base_id references base(id)
    id

products(base)
    base_id references base(id)
    id

contacts
    id
    base_id references base(id)
```

Comment: This is how I started in SQL Server but I thoght that it is good to use the PostgreSQL's inheritance. It seems that I will come back to what I had done in SQL Server. The inheritance has a lot of problems.